# optimal frame for a Riemann metric

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

In his excellent book, *Harmonic maps, conservation laws and moving frames*, Helein proves the existence of conformal coordinates on a surface, looking for an optimal frame. Let $\mathbb{D}$ equipped with a metric $g$ and fix a moving frame $\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2$. For a function $u:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we define the new frame $\vec{e}_1(u),\vec{e}_2(u)$. Then by minimising the functional

$$\int_D \vert \nabla \vec{e}_1(u)\vert^2 +\vert \nabla \vec{e}_1(u)\vert^2 \,dz,$$
he obtain a Coulomb frame, i.e 
$$d*(\omega_1^2)=0$$
with $\omega_1^2=\langle d\vec{e}_1, e_2\rangle$. This last condition is equivalent to the existence of $f$ such that $[e^f \vec{e}_1,e^f\vec{e}_2]=0$, which gives the desired result.

I am looking for a generalisation of this to higher dimension. Of course there is no conformal coordinates. But there must be an equivalent of the coulomb frame? it sounds like some Yang-Mills theory in the othonormal frame bundle, unfortunately, I am not an expert and I didn't find a clear reference. does anyone can suggest me something?

Comment: The higher dimensional analogue is harmonic coordinates. These were studied by Jost and Karcher, as well as Greene and Wu.

Comment: I am not looking for coordinates, but optimal frame which is less restrictive so we can expect something better.

Comment: You could also try to minimize the same functional.